# Effective way of reading text file in c# for line to line operation

Tags: c#, file-read

I'm having problem in reading text file for line to line addition  operation. I have used following syntax

`StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt");
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    string[] splitted = line.Split('#');
    string first = splitted[0].Trim();
    string second = splitted[1].Trim();`

I have used this syntax to separate the input from text file if file has following values.

12#15

15#7

13#14

23#31

```
 x= Convert.ToInt32(first);
 y= Convert.ToInt32(second);
 sum = x+y;
 txtBox.text = Convert.ToString(sum);
```

the problem is it only executes the last line. It only calculate the sum of 23 and 31 and show only but I want to add 12 and 15 first and show it in textbox similarly I want to add others.   please help me in forming appropriate syntax.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.  What code gets executed inside the `while` loop?  What do you mean by "it only executes the last line"?

Comment: look at my example @SangamJung and you will quickly see that you forgot to issue an `Initial Read()` before entering your `while loop`

Comment: I have tried to make my question  little bit clear. And thanx too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is *vague* one, however, I suggest using *Linq*:

```
  var source = File
    .ReadLines("input.txt")           // read line by line
    .Select(line => line.Split('#'))  // split each line
    //.Where(items => items.Length == 2)  // you may want to filter out the lines
    .Select(items => new {            // convert each line into anonymous class 
       first = items[0].Trim(),
       second = items[1].Trim()
     });
```

You can add as many `Select` (line to line opetations) as you want. Then you can proceed the items in a `foreach` loop:

```
  foreach (var item in source) { 
    ...
    // Let's read some fields from the anonymous object
    var first = item.first;
    var second = item.second; 
    ...
  }
```

**Edit:** according to the *edited* question you want just to sum up which can be done via *Linq* as well:

```
  var result = File
    .ReadLines("input.txt")   
    .Select(line => line.Split('#'))
    //.Where(items => items.Length == 2)  // you may want to filter out the lines
    .Sum(items => int.Parse(items[0]) + int.Parse(items[1]));

  txtBox.text = result.ToString();
```

Comment: what will be syntax for using values stored in first and second inside foreach loop

Comment: @Sangam Jung: just `item.first;` or/and `item.second;`

Comment: I have tried to make my question  little bit clear. And thanx too

Comment: @Sangam Jung: well, ut seems that you want to *sum up* the `first` and `last` which can be done with a help of *Linq* as well (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't only read the last line, you just never do anything with the other iterations. Currently you just keep reassigning `line` with the value of the latest line that has been read, I presume you hope to save these to a list or similar

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt");
string line;
List<string> allLines = new List<string>();
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
     allLines.Add(line);
```

Comment: Note: There are more concise ways to write this code, this answer just fixes the issue you mention in your question.

Comment: I have tried to make my question  little bit clear. And thanx too

Answer (score 0):

here you can test your File and Load The data into a DataTable this should be pretty straight forward.

```
DataTable dtTextFileData = new DataTable();
dtTextFileData.Columns.AddRange(new []
{
    new DataColumn("First", typeof(string)), 
    new DataColumn("Second", typeof(string)) 
});

StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\YourFilePath\input.txt");
string line = file.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    string[] fields = line.Split('#');
    DataRow dr = dtTextFileData.NewRow();
    dr["First"]  = fields[0].ToString();
    dr["Second"] = fields[1].ToString();
    dtTextFileData.Rows.Add(dr);
    line = file.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I have tried to make my question  little bit clear. And thanx too